# viewpager with previous and next fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is there a way to show all of(not part of) previous and next fragment in view pager? i did not find anything about that. sorry for if this question already asked.

this is what i want to do:
[image]

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you.